# Fitting tables into beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, scaling, height

I have some tables in my presentations that are rather big. I found out how to use `\resizebox` to fit them into my page. Unfortunately this only works for tables that are wide. For long tables, my method doesn't work. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Well formulated title}
   \include{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the file `table.tex` is

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888
\end{tabular}
}
```

As one can see this table is now too long for the page. So I thought that I could try `\resizebox{!}{\textheight}` instead of `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` but unfortunately this does not come out as expected.

Is there a possibility to determine the maximal height of the hbox so that my table is as high as possible without producing an overfull hbox?

I know that I could just set some values myself that kinda fit but I want to have a possibility to do it automatically.

Comment: Beyond the technical point, perhaps you should also ask yourself if your audience really needs to see such huge tables... Usually, when something does not fit into a slide, it is better not to try to make it fit by force.

Comment: I was kind of expecting a comment like that. I am completely aware of what you are saying. This question is more or less technical. My actual table almost fits, just some pt too high and wide. Nobody would actually see that. But I noticed the warnings and am looking for a solution.
Also, this could also be an issue if you want to show an image, but don't want to use `\frame[plain]` for some reason. But nevertheless thanks for the remark, maybe it'll help someone.

Answer (score 31):

You need rather less that `\textheight` to allow room for the title. Also, it's probably easier to use `adjustbox` than `\resizebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Well formulated title}
\centering
\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
           max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888
\end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\scalebox{}` instead of `\adjustbox` or `\resizebox`. It works for me wonders.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You can improve this answer by showing some example code and an image of the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Well formulated title}
   \include{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%table.tex%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
           max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 \\
111111 & 222222 & 3333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 & 66666666 & 77777777 & 88888888
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: "! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"